# Difference between B-frame and b-frame when decoding x264

Tags: video, encoding, x264

I'm trying to achieve the following frame-pattern when encoding with the x264-encoder:

```
IPBBPBBPBBPBBPBBI
```

So, basically I want every 16th frame to be an I-frame and between every 2 P-frames there have to be 2 B-frames. I use these parameters:

```
x264.exe -I 16 -i 16 --bframes 2 --b-adapt 0 --tune psnr --fps 25 --input-res 416x240
```

But this gives an output of

```
IPBbPBbPBbPBbPBbI
```

What is the difference between an uppercase B or a lowercase b in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question by searching even further. According to [this website](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MeGUI/x264_Settings#bframes) a B-frame is a frame that's used as a reference by other frames, while a b-frame is not used as reference by other frames.